# Failed to inject payload with Python requests library in DVWA forms

Tags: xss, python, dvwa

I have written a Python script to inject a payload through the `requests` library, but the payload is being added instead of injecting

```
xsstestscript=html.unescape("&lt;script&gt;alert&#40;1&#41;&lt;&#47;script&gt;")
```

the payload is being sent:

```
{'txtName': 'as', 'mtxMessage': '<script>alert(1)</script>', 'btnSign': 'submit', 'user_token': 'dd60d1773d4574153f809d7d1c1a8f65'}
```

to the following form:

```
<form method="post" name="guestform" "="">
            <table width="550" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td width="100">Name *</td>
                    <td><input name="txtName" type="text" size="30" maxlength="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100">Message *</td>
                    <td><textarea name="mtxMessage" cols="50" rows="3" maxlength="50"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="btnSign" type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook" onclick="return validateGuestbookForm(this.form);">
                        <input name="btnClear" type="submit" value="Clear Guestbook" onclick="return confirmClearGuestbook();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>

        </form>
```

It is being apparently injected like this:

[image]

But when i copy the same code in the DVWA website form and click on post it is injecting

I have tried the following:

- I have tried changing the encoding to UTF-8
- I have tried changing the encoding to ASCII
- If the same thing is being accepted by the form of that page then it should accept the Python request as well, right?

The security level is set low in my DVWA

Python code :
submit form

```
    def submit_form(self,form,value,url):
        # print(value)
        # print(form)
        global token
        action= form.get('action')
        post_url= urlparse.urljoin(url,action)

        method=form.get('method')
        # print(method)
        # input_token=input.get('user_token')
        # print(input_token)

        input_list=form.findAll("input")

        # print("122",input_list)
        textarea=form.findAll("textarea")
        # ure=self.session.get(url)
        # print("119",ure.content)
        for input in input_list:
            print("hum",input.get('type'))
            if input["type"]=="hidden":
                token=input.get('value')
                print (token)
                # print("129",p)
                # token= p
            else:
                p="none"
        # print("134",token)

        # print(textarea)
        post_data={}
        # token =token

        for input in input_list:

            print("130",input)
            for text in textarea:
                text_name=text.get('name')
                print("126",text_name)
            input_name=input.get('name')

            input_type=input.get('type')
            print("130",input_type)

            input_value=value
            # print(input_value)
            # input_value=input.get('value')
            if input["type"] == "text" or input["type"] == "search":
                # parsed_html.body.find('input', attrs={'name':'user_token'}).get("value")
                                # input_value=value
                # print(input_value)
                post_data[input_name]="as"
                post_data['mtxMessage']=input_value
                post_data['btnSign'] = "submit"
                post_data['user_token'] = token


                print("this data 140",post_data)

            # print(post_data)
            if method == 'post':
                # print("post method")
                # print(post_data)
                s=self.session.post(post_url,data=post_data)
                # print("printing this 141",s.content)

                # print(s.headers)
                # print("requestpost",s.status_code)
                return s
            return self.session.get(post_url,params=post_data)
            print("get req")
```

XSS payload part:

```
def test_xss_in_form1(self):

        url = 'http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php'
        resp = self.session.get(url)
        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features="html.parser")
        input_value = parsed_html.body.find('input', attrs={'name':'user_token'}).get("value")
        # print("169",input_value)
        data_dict = {"username": "admin", "password": "password", "Login": "Login", "user_token":input_value}
        response = self.session.post(url, data_dict)
        # print("response 160",response.url)
        # s=requests.Session()

        urll="http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/xss_s/"

        gett= self.session.get(urll)
        # print("166",gett.url)
        # print(gett.url)
        if gett != urll:
            get= self.session.get(urll)

            # print("insideloop",get.content)

            # print("it didnt work")
        else:
            get=gett
            print('it did')
        # get= requests.get("http://192.168.56.101/webgoat.net/Content/StoredXSS.aspx",allow_redirects=True)
        # print(get.url)

        # print(",<<<<<<<---------",get.history)

        # if get.status_code == 302:
        #     get= requests.get("http://192.168.56.101/webgoat.net/Content/StoredXSS.aspx", allow_redirects=False)
        #     print("thisget",get)

        # print(get.status_code)
        parsed_html= BeautifulSoup(get.content, 'html.parser')

        # print(parsed_html)
        ph= parsed_html.findAll('form')
        # for f in ph:
        # print("192",ph[0])
        #     print(f)

        # url="http://192.168.56.101/webgoat.net/Content/StoredXSS.aspx"
        # xsstestscript=html.unescape("&lt;script&gt;alert&#40;&quot;checl&quot;&#41;&lt;&#47;script&gt;")
        # xsstestscript="<script>alert(1);</script>"
        # xsstestscript=html.unescape("&lt;script&gt;alert&#40;&#x22;checl&#x22;&#41;&lt;&#47;script&gt;")
        xsstestscript=html.unescape("&lt;script&gt;alert&#40;1&#41;&lt;&#47;script&gt;")

        # xsstestscript=html.unescape("&lt;script&gt;alert&#40;&#147;checl&#147;&#41;&lt;&#47;script&gt;")
        # quo=html.unescape("&#34;")
        # xsstestscript=html.unescape("&lt;script&gt;alert&#40;\x22 ;chec&#34;&#41;;&lt;&#47;script&gt;")
        # xsstestscript=html.unescape("&lt;script&gt;alert&#40;%20;chec&#xFF02;&#41;&lt;&#47;script&gt;")
        # xsstestscript= '''<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>'''
 # xsstestscript.encode('ascii',errors="backslashreplace")
        print(xsstestscript)


        # print(xsstestscript)
        response=self.submit_form(ph[0],xsstestscript,urll)
        parsed_html_after= BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        # print(parsed_html_after)

        # print(response)
        if xsstestscript in response.text:
            print ('heyy we got one xss')
            return True
        else:

            print('not vul')
```

Comment: When you copy what code? There's a lot of "wand-waviness" to your details. It is better if you actually post what you've done rather than merely describing it. For instance, those little quote marks make a huge difference, and so does Python's encoding.

Comment: @schroeder edited the question pls check